# Can not update or install after changing DHCP IP to Static IP

Tags: raspbian, static-ip

Can anyone help me configure Raspbian Jessie with a static IP? Whenever I change my IP to static I am not able to install any package, nor I am able to update my Pi. All of this works when I work on a dynamic IP.

Even when I try to ping to any website like google I get an error:

```
ping: unknown host google.com
```

Comment: share all your `/etc/network/interface` and try pinging your router. also your `goolge.com` is not a hostname

Comment: Did you configure your DNS settings as well? Please share the settings that you are using as the above commentor asks.

Comment: Please also provide what steps you followed to setup your static ip.

Answer (score 1):

Setting static IP involves also to modify <kbd>/etc/resolv.conf</kbd> there, you must have your default dns server. Use just 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 or one from your ISP vendor.

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
search xxxx.com
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: I even modified /etc.resolv.conf file, but on reboot this file just shows default IP that is 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I append `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` by the following code:

```
Interface eth0
Static ip_address=(myip)
Static router=(gateway)
Static domain_name_server=8.8.8.8
```

After rebooting my pi I am able to get the static IP  I configured but than I am not able to either upadate nor install any if the packages.
Even tried the old method of configuring static IP by editing `/etc/network/interface`s but still no difference